# Repository and packaging standard for open-source smart-contract modules

Tags: repositories, contract-development

Is there a standard way to package the source code of a smart contract and publish it on a public repository? In such a way to enable structured reuse, with versioning and easy ways to update an component. Similar to what [search.maven.org](http://search.maven.org) for Java, [bower](http://bower.io/) and [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/) for JavaScript or [PyPI](https://pypi.python.org/pypi) for Python offers.

There's a repository of sample contracts on https://github.com/ethereum/dapp-bin and various blog posts and sites containing sample code of smart contracts. However, this doesn't solve the problem of copy&paste code and versioning.

Comment: Sounds like a good dApp idea ;-P

Comment: @HodlDwon that already exists as dapp, see my answer.

Answer (score 2):

There is no single standard for smart contract code sharing, but [Dapple](https://github.com/NexusDevelopment/dapple) is taking a swing at being Ethereum's npm. (Full disclosure: I get paid to work on Dapple.)

Answer (score 1):

Package management via `npm` is available in Truffle beta: http://truffleframework.com/tutorials/package-management

A larger package standard beyond `npm` is in the works, which will hopefully be a collaboration between the major tool authors and the Ethereum Foundation. More details to come.

Answer (score 0):

There is the **DApp-Store**. I'm currently at the Berlin Ethereum meetup and it's discussed to be included some day into the mist browser.

Try the live [frontier demo](http://dappstore.io). Or the [morden testnet demo](http://morden.dappstore.io).

[image: Screenshot on Morden]

How to use:

- Download [Mist 0.3.6 here](https://github.com/ethereum/mist/releases/tag/0.3.6): that's the only "browser" version.
- Sync the blockchain with your network of your choice.
- Create an account if you don't have one already, and transfer some Ether to it.
- Navigate to one of the above URLs within Mist, depending on what chain you're on.

Comment: Author of the dapp store here. Unfortunately the dapp store has been discontinued for now. It will likely be revived in the future.